# Getting Correct Type Name in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In the Chrome console I type:

```
function test() {}
```

Than I type:

```
new test()
```

Now Google prints "test {}" in the console.
When I do:

```
new test() instanceof test
```

It prints true.

On `new test().toString()` it returns [object Object].
On `new test().constructor` it returns undefined.
On `new test().prototype` it returns undefined.
On `new test().__proto__` it returns test {}.

So what is the deal?

This is just a stipped down problem of a 3rd party framework. So I can not just add a class literal, add a constructor myself, add any other fancy idea. Since Chrome already knows the correct type (name of the constructor method) I just ask myself: "How can I optain the information?".

Thanks,

Martin (Kersten)

Comment: What version of Chrome are you on? I have no problem with `new test().constructor`

Comment: I already typed that in the console and now it works. Actually it was a typo all day long. I always wrote constuctor. <- Missing an 'r' hard to notice... .

Answer (score -1):

You mean getting a string from a boolean?

You can do that by creating a new function:

```
function boolToString(bool boolToTransf) {
    if (boolToTransf == true) {
        return "true";
    } else {
        return "false";
    }
}
```

Now just type in:
    boolToString(test());

And you'll get "true" or "false" as string.

Comment: I wanted to get the test. Actually constructor (notice the r) is returning the function definition that created the object using the new operator. This way the problem is now considered to be solve.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: It works in Chrome. I just typed constructor wrongly and got a undefined instead.

For everyone reading this I did a typo all day long. I wrote constuctor several times and sure there is an r missing. Lucky me ssube pointed it out when I noticed that I wrote it differently and was about to try it with the 'r'. Thanks for attention.

I will leave this answer / question active for every other German doing this typo.

Thanks,

Martin (Kersten)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I updated the answer to be more clear. It is the answer to my question.

Comment: Questions caused by typos or non-reproducible errors are off-topic for Stack Overflow. This question is both a duplicate and would also be off-topic on its own merits.

Comment: I tried to delete it with no luck. So I flagged it for moderation. Please delete.